# Understanding Lemma 13.2 in Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let
$$\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}}:=\{U\subseteq X\mid \forall\, x\in U\, \exists\, B\in \mathcal{B}:x\in B\subseteq U \}$$
where $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$. In Munkres' book, it has shown that the collection $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}}$ is a topology on $X$, and it is called the topology generated by the basis $\mathcal{B}$. Each basis element of $\mathcal{B}$ is open in $X$, because $\mathcal{B}$ is in $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}}$. Let's look at the lemma,

> **Lemma 13.2.** Let $X$ be a topological space. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open sets of $X$ such that for each open set $U$ of $X$ and each $x$ in $U$, there is an element $C$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $x\in C\subset U$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for the topology of $X$.

Doesn't it mean that if the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal{C}$, then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}$? Or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I think the following should clarify whatever you're confused about.  If $\mathcal{T}$ is a specific topology, then "$\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}$" is defined to mean that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$ and $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{T}$.  So Lemma 13.2 is stating that if a topology $\mathcal{T}$ is *given* (namely, the given topology on $X$) and $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies the stated hypotheses, then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for a topology and in fact the topology it generates is $\mathcal{T}$.